# Compiler error when trying to use release method

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, compiler-errors

This is slightly confusing for me because I'm reading an Objective-C book from 2009 (it's the only edition my library had) and the author constantly reminds the reader to release memory, but I get an error when I try to use this method. I read up a little about it and I found out that the release method is deprecated, but is there something I need to do instead of the release method to manage memory, or does Objective-C have garbage collection now?

For example:

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] init];
[s release];
```

Comment: It's kinda 50/50 whether it would be better to turn off ARC and learn the old stuff first, or instead leave ARC on and just learn the new paradigm.  It's good to understand the old scheme, since you get a much better feel for what ARC is doing "under the covers" -- stuff that will help you when you're shooting bugs related to memory management (and also help you when trying to understand some of the ARC interfaces and terminology).  But it does take significant effort/patience to learn the old stuff -- not exactly instant gratification.

Comment: Agreed with Hot Licks, though I'd even put it at 51/49 in favor of using ARC. There's plenty of other framework stuff you'll need to learn, and ARC is likely to only improve. Going back and learning about memory management when you have everything else well in hand seems like a good route to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not garbage collection but `Automatic Reference Counting` (`ARC`) at work for you.

To follow the examples in your book, create a new project in Xcode and deselect the option to use ARC.

Comment: thanks. Do you recommend that I disable this to follow the examples in the book or should I take advantage of ARC?

Comment: If it is your first book, I recommend disabling ARC to learn first hand what memory management means. Once you understand what happens under the hood, it is okay (actually cool) to turn on ARC.

Comment: I have experience with Java, but no memory management experience so far so I'll disable ARC. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have ARC enabled; calls to `retain` and `release` are automatically inserted by the compiler. If you want to do the memory management manually, disable ARC in the target’s build settings. On OS X, there is also garbage collection but it is deprecated.